# Create a two headed arrow connector in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Is it possible to create this in inkscape? It would be very useful in flow diagrams. At the moment I have two arrows and it becomes a mess when it needs to be repositioned:

[image]

I tried drawing two connectors and combining them, then using snap at midpoint feature to some what connect them. It produced a decent result:

[image]

But I am having problems scaling, to have it fit a certain space while maintaining the line thickness.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single path is linear so it can't branch into two at one point.  But you can achieve this with two paths.

1. Draw an open path containing three nodes, making sure the middle node is symmetrical (ie not a corner).
2. Draw a second open path with two nodes.  One of those two nodes should be placed in the exact same place as the middle node from the first path.
3. Group these two paths or combine them so that it's harder to accidentally separate them.

Now it's true that if you want to manipulate the shape of these paths you have to do it to two paths and keep moving the shorter one so it still goes to the mid-point.  But that's not too much effort.

Comment: thanks I tried that but when I run the extension to colour match the markers (the arrowheads are not being coloured same as the line)